# problem with code to combine two images in android?

Tags: android, image-processing

i am using the below code for combining two images.

```
    Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.me);
    Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.static);
    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(map);
    Bitmap out1 = null ;
    comboImage.setBitmap(out1);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(pic, 600, 350, null);
```

i am assuming that the i can use the bitmap out1 for getting the final image. but 'comboImage.setBitmap(out1);' line is causing a crash. without this line i am not able to see any images. how can i get the final combined image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the final image to be `out1`, you would do it like this:

```
Bitmap out1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(...);
Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(out1);
comboImage.drawBitmap(map, ...);
comboImage.drawBitmap(pic, ...);
```

`out1` would then be the merge images

Comment: thanks Matt. but if i add one more line at the end "  imView.setImageBitmap(out1); "   app is crashing. did i miss anything?

Comment: or how can i save the bitmap out1 ?

Comment: it is solved now. i was missing "imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);"   thanks Matt.