# Photo Frame development android

Tags: android, photo

I am new in android development. I want to merge frame image and photo .The merge image will be saved.
How can I merge photo and frame in one single png and save it to sdcard or memory.

Comment: Have you got solution? i have same problem. can you explain?

Answer (score 4):

click link below to find your answer

[here](http://kevindion.com/2011/01/android-bitmap-blending-color-channels/)
Android Bitmap Blending – Color Channels by Kevin Dion

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191265/problem-with-code-to-combine-two-images-in-android) a stack overflow post

hope help

Comment: Your tutorial is great . But I don't know how to convert original image to red,green,blue and alpha mode.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you need to perform blending b/w two images first is your frame and second is your base image see updated link

Comment: I think your previous tutorial is clearly understand for me . Please update your link .

Comment: Simple Link is not an answer, you should write something by describing the link. @DeepakSwami